# Nginx Ingress - Unable to write event

Tags: nginx, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am creating an nginx ingress on GKE.

On every reload event my controller prints to log:

> I1019 13:23:31.679126       6 controller.go:145] "Configuration
> changes detected, backend reload required" I1019 13:23:31.776558
> 6 controller.go:162] "Backend successfully reloaded" I1019
> 13:23:31.776897       6 event.go:282]
> Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-development",
> Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-6d55d6b5cd-g2rqh",
> UID:"109bb50d-b842-4e78-a9a4-ae3d4fc10166", APIVersion:"v1",
> ResourceVersion:"347936024", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason:
> 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration E1019
> 13:23:31.777294       6 event.go:273] Unable to write event: 'can't
> patch an event with namespace 'ingress-development' in namespace
> 'development'' (may retry after sleeping)

My controller configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ingress-development
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx

---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-serviceaccount.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.4.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.40.2
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-development
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.4.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.40.2
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-development
data:
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/clusterrole.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.4.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.40.2
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: ingress-nginx
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - endpoints
      - nodes
      - pods
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - nodes
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - services
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - update
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - events
    verbs:
      - create
      - patch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingressclasses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/clusterrolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.4.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.40.2
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: ingress-nginx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ingress-nginx
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-nginx
    namespace: ingress-development
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-role.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.4.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.40.2
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-development
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - pods
      - secrets
      - endpoints
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - services
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - update
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingressclasses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - configmaps
    resourceNames:
      - ingress-controller-leader-nginx
    verbs:
      - get
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - configmaps
    verbs:
      - create
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - endpoints
    verbs:
      - create
      - get
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - events
    verbs:
      - create
      - patch
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-rolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.4.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.40.2
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-development
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: ingress-nginx
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-nginx
    namespace: ingress-development
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-service-webhook.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.4.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.40.2
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller-admission
  namespace: ingress-development
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: https-webhook
      port: 443
      targetPort: webhook
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.4.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.40.2
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-development
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  loadBalancerIP: "MY_IP"
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.4.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.40.2
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-development
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  minReadySeconds: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      containers:
        - name: controller
          image: k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.40.2@sha256:46ba23c3fbaafd9e5bd01ea85b2f921d9f2217be082580edc22e6c704a83f02f
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /wait-shutdown
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
            - --ingress-class=nginx
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --validating-webhook=:8443
            - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
            - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
            - --watch-namespace=development
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
              add:
                - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            runAsUser: 101
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - name: LD_PRELOAD
              value: /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 5
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
              protocol: TCP
            - name: webhook
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: webhook-cert
              mountPath: /usr/local/certificates/
              readOnly: true
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 90Mi
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      volumes:
        - name: webhook-cert
          secret:
            secretName: ingress-nginx-admission
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/validating-webhook.yaml
# before changing this value, check the required kubernetes version
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#prerequisites
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.4.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.40.2
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
webhooks:
  - name: validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
    rules:
      - apiGroups:
          - networking.k8s.io
        apiVersions:
          - v1beta1
          - v1
        operations:
          - CREATE
          - UPDATE
        resources:
          - ingresses
    failurePolicy: Fail
    sideEffects: None
    admissionReviewVersions:
      - v1
      - v1beta1
    clientConfig:
      service:
        namespace: ingress-development
        name: ingress-nginx-controller-admission
        path: /networking/v1beta1/ingresses
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/serviceaccount.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.4.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.40.2
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-development
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/clusterrole.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.4.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.40.2
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - admissionregistration.k8s.io
    resources:
      - validatingwebhookconfigurations
    verbs:
      - get
      - update
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/clusterrolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.4.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.40.2
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-nginx-admission
    namespace: ingress-development
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/role.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.4.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.40.2
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-development
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - get
      - create
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/rolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.4.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.40.2
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-development
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-nginx-admission
    namespace: ingress-development
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/job-createSecret.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission-create
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.4.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.40.2
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-development
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: ingress-nginx-admission-create
      labels:
        helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.4.1
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.40.2
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: create
          image: docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.3.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          args:
            - create
            - --host=ingress-nginx-controller-admission,ingress-nginx-controller-admission.$(POD_NAMESPACE).svc
            - --namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)
            - --secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission
          env:
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx-admission
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 2000
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/job-patchWebhook.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission-patch
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.4.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.40.2
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-development
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: ingress-nginx-admission-patch
      labels:
        helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.4.1
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.40.2
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: patch
          image: docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.3.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          args:
            - patch
            - --webhook-name=ingress-nginx-admission
            - --namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)
            - --patch-mutating=false
            - --secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission
            - --patch-failure-policy=Fail
          env:
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx-admission
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 2000
```

Ingress Configuration:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-ingress
  namespace: development
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    # Enable client certificate authentication
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
    # Create the secret containing the trusted ca certificates
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "development/client-cert-api-ingress"
    # Specify the verification depth in the client certificates chain
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "1"
    # Automatically redirect http to https
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    # Use regex in paths
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    # For notifications we add the proxy headers
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |  
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - example.com
    - secretName: api-tls-certificate
  rules:
  # - host: example.com
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: v2-api-frontend
          servicePort: 443
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What GKE version are you using? How did you deploy nginx ingress, using `Helm` or apply configuration from nginx site? What did you change after deploy? Do you want to change `namesapce` of ingress?

Comment: GKE version 1.16.13-gke.401. I applied the nginx configuration while changing the namespace from nginx-ingress to ingress-development in order to be able to deploy multiple nginx controllers(one for development and one for production namespaces). The exact custom config is found in the question.

Comment: So if I would like to reproduce your steps it would be: 1. Deploy nginx ingress; 2. Change namesapace in that ingress and reaload it; 3. Deploy new ingress. Did you make any changes to `--ingress-class` or certificates? Could you describe all steps you did? To confirm, you want to have `Multiple **Nginx Ingress** controllers` ?

Comment: My main goal is to have two ingresses, one for prod and one for dev. The steps I basically did was taking the yaml from the nginx docs and change the namespace from ingress-nginx to ingress-development. Also added - --watch-namespace=development. Then applied it and applied the ingress. Probably I broke something while making this change but I can't figure out what. I believe this is something related to permissions within the cluster. The source yaml i changed is from here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.40.2/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml

Comment: I believe that you can recreate using the following steps: 1. Deploy my controller yaml. 2. Create development with a service in it. 3. Create ingress in development ns. 4. Watch the logs of the controller on reload event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your scenario but using [Helm](https://helm.sh/).

**Original Replication Steps to create 2 Nginx Ingress in one Cluster**

Create two `namespaces` for development: `dev1`, `dev2` and two for `ingress`: `ing1`, `ing2`.

```
$ kubectl create ns dev1
$ kubectl create ns dev2
$ kubectl create ns ing1
$ kubectl create ns ing2
```

Download [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) repo to local environment.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
```

Enter path with charts.

```
$ cd /home/user/ingress-nginx/charts/ingress-nginx
```

Deploy 1st `Nginx Ingress Controller`

```
helm install ing1 . --set controller.ingressClass=ing1 --set controller.scope.enabled=true --set controller.scope.namespace=dev1 -n ing1
```

Deploy 2nd `Nginx Ingress Controller`

```
helm install ing2 . --set controller.ingressClass=ing2 --set controller.scope.enabled=true --set controller.scope.namespace=dev2 -n ing2
```

Both Ingresses will be created succesfully, however specific entry will occur:

```
I1021 16:07:31.719665       6 controller.go:173] "Initial sync, sleeping for 1 second"
E1021 16:07:31.719920       6 event.go:273] Unable to write event: 'can't create an event with namespace 'ing1' in namespace 'dev1'' (may retry after sleeping)
I1021 16:07:31.719951       6 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ing1", Name:"ing1-ingress-nginx-controller-7dcb46fb9c-p7qg8", UID:"38823c84-c7f3-4209-XXXX-3951398fb48d", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"111729", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
E1021 16:07:35.835493       6 event.go:273] Unable to write event: 'can't create an event with namespace 'ing1' in namespace 'dev1'' (may retry after sleeping)
E1021 16:07:45.835793       6 event.go:273] Unable to write event: 'can't create an event with namespace 'ing1' in namespace 'dev1'' (may retry after sleeping)
```

But if you will create `Nginx Ingress Controller` in the same `Namespace` that will be monitored, this issue will not occur.

In new cluster created only 2 `namespaces`: `dev1` and `dev2`.

```
$ kubectl create ns dev1
$ kubectl create ns dev2
```

Deploy two nginx ingress controllers (same method like previous one, download repo to local machine, etc):

```
$ helm install dev1 . --set controller.ingressClass=dev1 --set controller.scope.enabled=true --set controller.scope.namespace=dev1 -n dev1

$ helm install dev2 . --set controller.ingressClass=dev2 --set controller.scope.enabled=true --set controller.scope.namespace=dev2 -n dev2
```

**Logs output:**

```
I1021 16:24:16.207839       6 controller.go:173] "Initial sync, sleeping for 1 second"
I1021 16:24:16.208050       6 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"dev1", Name:"dev1-ingress-nginx-controller-8444854ff4-8bdfm", UID:"e3168581-f6e7-43f5-b655-2aae07b980a2", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"8689", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
$
```

In addition, as per [Multiple Nginx Ingress Controllers](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/) docs, you must specify `--ingress-class` if you want to run more `Ingress controllers` in one cluster.

> Deploying multiple Ingress controllers, of different types (e.g., ingress-nginx & gce), and not specifying a class annotation will result in both or all controllers fighting to satisfy the Ingress, and all of them racing to update Ingress status field in confusing ways.

> When running multiple `ingress-nginx controllers`, it will only process an unset class annotation if one of the controllers uses the default `--ingress-class` value (see `IsValid` method in internal/ingress/annotations/class/main.go), otherwise the class annotation become required.

> If `--ingress-class` is set to the default value of nginx, the controller will monitor Ingresses with no class annotation and Ingresses with annotation class set to nginx. Use a non-default value for `--ingress-clas`s, to ensure that the controller only satisfied the specific class of Ingresses.

In short, deploying `Nginx Ingress controller` in the same `Namespace` that will be monitored does not showing this entry.
However, even if this specific entry occurs `Nginx Ingress` worked as expected.

Did you encounter any issues with `Nginx Ingress` work, or just wanted to rid off this entry?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It didn't affect me as far as I know, just wanted to get rid off this.